# UIMoviePlayerController ... Can it be used?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a headache regarding the movie player launched by a UIWebView in one of my apps.

I would like to call some actions from these triggers :

```
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullcreenNotification
```

(not `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification`, which doesn't work in this case...)

The UIMoviePlayer calls work, but I am unable to find the documentation for these, and therefor fear that it might be rejected due to "use of undocumented / private framework"

Have anyone had luck finding the documentation for these ? Or know if one is allowed to use these in a real app ?

Comment: The Movie Player launched by UIWebView will not register these notifications,coz its launched in its own `UIWindow` and you have no control over it. Its kind of Bug in Apple framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, these notifications are **not** documented.

They have actually changed name since iOS 4.3 and are now called

```
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
```

and

```
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification
```

(Fullscreen instead of Fullcreen).

Since they are still undocumented, i wouldn't advise using them if you are planning to release your app on the App Store.

However, there may be workarounds, as suggested by H2CO3 in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554077/1081831):

If you want to know when the video started or stopped playing, you could use the `onplaying` and/or `onended` events of the HTML5 `<video>` container, and call a URL which you can intercept in the webview's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method to execute the code you want.

[HTML5 Event Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have tried. These notification don't work any more in iOS 6.1.2. But it work on iOS 6.1. I tested on iPod gen5