# is that UIWebView player a MPMoviePlayerController instance, and how to get a reference to that instance?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to play a youtube video in UIWebview and handle the event when user click the DOne button and when the video finish playing. I think of the solution that will handle the event that sent from UIWebview's media player.

My question is:
1. is that the UIWebview's media player a MPMoviewPlayerController?
2. How do i refer to that instance and handle the event it sent out (such as: pause, stop, done, finish playing...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1. is that the UIWebview's media player a MPMoviewPlayerController?***

No.

***2. How do i refer to that instance and handle the event it sent out (such as: pause, stop, done, finish playing...)***

As drafted in my answer to a very similar question:
[How to receive NSNotifications from UIWebView embedded YouTube video playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback/8554040#8554040)