# iOS - How do you know if the device is playing something?

Tags: ios, html5-video, statusbar

I need to know when an HTML video started playing. I see that when it does this little play icon appears in the status bar.

I would like to know if my iOS device has that little play icon in the status bar or not.

Is there a method to call in order to know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would capture one of these notifications:

```
MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification
MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
```

But since it's from a `UIWebView` you will not receive these notifications, 
You might try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback/#8554077).

Answer (score 0):

Html5 specifies

> `media.played`
>
> Returns a TimeRanges object that represents the ranges of the media resource that the user agent has played.

But I'm not sure how many browsers yet support this. The specification suggests that no browser has full support for the API.

Comment: Hi nes, i see you edited the title of my question. But like this meaning is different! Infact mine was not a question about html5, but about iOS.