# Shifted UINavigationBar after rotation during MPMoviePlayer fullscreen playback in a UIWebview

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, rotation, mpmovieplayer, navigationbar

I searched on the web but I didn't find any solution.

That is my problem:

I embed YouTube videos in a UIWebView. It works, but when I enter the fullscreen playback and rotate my iPad, the UINavigationBar is shifted (see the picture below). I know that there is no direct control of the video player in a web view, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks

[Splitted Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcI1B.png)

Comment: i had the same issue.. how did you fix this..thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's no way to resolve this problem using MPMoviePlayerNotification, because UIWebView Video Don't use MPMoviePlayerViewController or it's private for developer.
But, there's another way to fix this bug.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleStatusBarFrameDidChange)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)handleStatusBarFrameDidChange {
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar problem on my iPhone app.

I wonder if this is the right way but for now the code below solved it.

**1. Added observers in the webivew's initialize method.**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

The observers should be removed when you don't need them no longer. I just put the code in the webview's dealloc method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

**2. Hide the navigation bar when the movie started and show it again when the movie finished.**

* contentsViewController in the code is the owner of my webview. so just in my case.

```
- (void)youTubeStarted:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.contentsViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

- (void)youTubeFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.contentsViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

I got the way from [How to receive NSNotifications from UIWebView embedded YouTube video playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback)

Comment: The only issue with this is UIMoviePlayerController is a private API. Does anyone have any experience of successful submissions using these notifications?