# Is there a way to get the length of a video playing in my UIWebView? Can I start my movie at a certain position?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I think the current answer for iOS 6 and less is NO, but here's my question anyway:

I want to open my movie via a `UIWebView` at 5 minutes into the video... is this possible?

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:movie.fileURL]];
```

I also want to get the time position of the video when the user hits the Done button. Is that possible? I looked at some undocumented notifications and I couldn't find much for this either. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback).

Answer (score -1):

My walk around way to solve what you want is to use another player instead of the `UIWebView`. Such as `MPMoviePlayerController` or `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Then do what you want is much easier.