# Swift: How to access player object of full screen HTML video?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to hold a reference to the `AVPlayer` instance that takes over the screen when playing HTML videos full screen from embedded browsers. My first approach was this:

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {

    override public func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      print("herezzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz") // prints correctly
      print(self.player) // prints nil
    }
}
```

However it always returns nil. So I'm trying a different approach. I want to override either the initializer or `play` method of AVPlayer but I can't seem to do it without getting objective-c selector conflicts.

```
import AVKit
import MediaPlayer

extension AVPlayer {
  override func play() { // this doesn't work. just an example of what i want
    super.play()

    print("do stuff here")
  }
}
```

Is there a way to override one of AVPlayer's instance methods so I can store a reference to `self`? Or is it not even an AVPlayer?

Comment: Didn't this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift

Comment: i want a reference to the default player that opens up when playing videos in am embedded browser, not play videos manually with a URL

Answer (score 1):

"The most important classes used for playing video content within that UIWebView are called MPAVController and UIMoviePlayerController". So you can't get the instance of AVPlayer.

Please check this question: [How to receive NSNotifications from UIWebView embedded YouTube video playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override methods from an extension. Or more precisely, the compiler allows you to do so, but it doesn't work. See this thread: [Overriding methods in Swift extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions)

You're also not supposed to subclass `AVPlayerViewController`.

Why can't you just read the `AVPlayerViewController`s `player` property in the class that creates it?

Comment: i'm trying to do this for all videos that go full screen from my embedded browser so i want a global way of grabbing the `player` that takes over the screen

Comment: I think you're out of luck then.